# how to remove white space from first and last in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I don't want any space before the input and after the input like "  text" and "text  " does not allow so I replace the white space but when we copy "text        " from notepad and paste over the input and want to remove the space it throws error like "can not read property of undefined reading target".so how to do like when user give space front and back its automatically replace whitespace

```
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
  };
  const handleChangeWhiteSpace = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.includes(" ")) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    }
  };

<MyInput
                          type="text" style={{width:'240px'}}
                          error={formik.errors.input && formik.touched.input}
                          value={formik.values.input}
                          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                          onChange={(e)=>{formik.handleChange(e);handleChangeWhiteSpace()}}
                          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                          name="input"
                          id="input"
                          autoFocus={false}
                          autoComplete="off"
/>
```

Comment: trim - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: If `target` is undefined, you could try `currentTarget`. Not certain of the exact layout of your DOM, but that could be a possible fix.

Comment: Also, you need to pass `e` to the `handleChangeWhiteSpace` function call

Comment: in handleChangeWhiteSpace i also defined replace() but when we want to paste with space it throws error "can not read property of undefined reading target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using regex the following should work, you can test it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/):

```
e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/gm, "");
```

the cleaner solution would be what sojin suggested

```
e.target.value = e.target.value.trim()
```

Comment: yes I got it but when i am copy "text        " from notepad and paste to input field it should be remove the white space like "text" but it is not reflecting

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  const handleChangeWhiteSpace = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.includes(" ")) {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    }
  };
```

With this

```
  const handleChangeWhiteSpace = (e) => {
      e.target.value = e.clipboardData.getData('Text').trim();
  };
```

To register changes when you paste text inside the text field use the onPaste event

```
onPaste={handleChangeWhiteSpace}
```

Final Code

```
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    
  };
  const handleChangeWhiteSpace = (e) => {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.trim();
  };

<MyInput
                          type="text" style={{width:'240px'}}
                          error={formik.errors.input && formik.touched.input}
                          value={formik.values.input}
                          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                          onPaste={handleChangeWhiteSpace}
                          onChange={(e)=>{formik.handleChange(e);
                          handleChangeWhiteSpace()}}
                          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                          name="input"
                          id="input"
                          autoFocus={false}
                          autoComplete="off"
/>
```

Comment: yes I got it but when i am copy "text        " from notepad and paste to input field it should be remove the white space like "text" but it is not reflecting

Comment: You could add onPaste for your input element, I have changed my code look into it.

Comment: yes after adding it gives error like  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Comment: @SougataMukherjee That might be because the target value is null. I think we need to use **e.clipboardData.getData('Text')**. I have edited my answer, let me know if it's working

Answer (score 1):

use **normalize={(value, prevVal, prevVals) => value.trimStart()}** after rules{[]} in form.item

for prevent whitespace before value in antd input

for example check selected code in image ==>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD0ly.png)

Answer (score 0):

To dont allow to send only spaces you can use **normalize** prop

```
<MyInput
   type="text" style={{width:'240px'}}
   normalize={(value) => value.trimStart()}
   error={formik.errors.input && formik.touched.input}
   value={formik.values.input}
```

and then you can remove all of the spaces inside of this function

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
 //values.input1=values.input1.trim() or whatever
}
```

btw this function you can use to remove all the spaces

```
const remove = (str) => str.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use to remove white spaces at start and end using trimStart() and trimEnd().

```
 e.target.value = e.target.value.trimStart().trimEnd();
```